# TLS with OAuth2.0 in K8s application

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, oauth-2.0, tls1.3

I am trying to configure my K8s app with TLS. I have 2 containers in that pod, one is OAuth2.0 proxy container and the other container has my backend code.

I am using OAuth2.0 for doing that. So basically, in the OAuth2.0 proxy pod, I provide tls-cert-file and tls-key-file. As I am using OAuth2.0 for authorisation, I figured I can use the same pod to enable HTTPS. However, after OAuth provider redirects to my application, I get 502 bad gateway.

This is the error I obtain in the OAuth container:

```
Error proxying to upstream server: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

Now I am wondering is this I have configured TLS only on OAuth container and not the backend container?

Or is this something else and configuring TLS on OAuth container is enough?

Comment: We need more details to troubleshoot your issue. Could you include your yaml files? Is your cluster behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more tinkering I figured out what was wrong. The error I mentioned above basically means that we're trying to send HTTPS request to a server that typically takes HTTP request.

In my OAuth proxy conf, I had changed `upstream` to `https` whereas it should be `HTTP`.

I was able to establish an end to end encrypted connection after making this change.

Comment: year it should https, as you are trying to do authZ with tls so.

Comment: @HarshManvar you can think of it like auth2.0 is doing a call internally. My upstream is  http://localhost. So it works well without HTTPS